# Fail with error 'UniswapV2Library: ZERO_ADDRESS' when trying to implement a swap

Tags: ropsten, uniswap

I am trying to implement a Ropsten Testnet swap via contract. This contract swaps Testnet DAI for a token I have created. Liquidity is added and swapping via the UI works.

```
IUniswapV2Router02 private router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);
Token public token; //address passed via constructor 
ERC20 public stablecoin = ERC20(0xaD6D458402F60fD3Bd25163575031ACDce07538D); //DAI 
address[] paths = [address(stablecoin), address(token)]; 

unction swapper (uint buyValue, uint minAmount, uint time) public {
        require(msg.sender==owner, "only contract owner");
        router.swapExactTokensForTokens(buyValue, minAmount, paths, address(this), time);
    }
```

When I run the swapper function, it returns Fail with error 'UniswapV2Library: ZERO_ADDRESS'. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the paths like this for some reason

```
cvxPath = new address[](2);
cvxPath[0] = address(stablecoin);
cvxPath[1] = address(token);
```